# \raisebox for multirows

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

Is there a way to apply `\raisebox` to the multirow option? I want to vertically center some images that span several rows in a table. A different solution would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: I figured out that you can use the `fixup` parameter to manually align the content of a multirow, though this isn't an ideal solution.

Edit: An image of the table in it's current state:
[image]

The code is horribly formatted and won't be very useful with example images as I scaled the images instead of giving them a fixed size, but here is the snippet just in case:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c@{}}
        & & \multirow{3}{*}{Grundwerkstoff}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Stumpfstoß (Gurtstoß)} & Gurtstoß & \multirow{3}{*}{\specialcell{Stegblech-\\querstoß\\(Hauptspng)}}& \multirow{3}{*}{\specialcell{Gurtstoß\\Kastenträger}} & \multirow{3}{*}{Rohrstumpfstoß} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\specialcell{Rohrverbindung\\ mit Vollrundwerkstoff}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\specialcell{Winklige \\ Rohrverbindung}}\\\cline{4-6}
        &&&gleiche&ungleiche&ungleiche&&&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&\\
        &&&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Blechdicke}&&&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&\\\hline
        &\multirow{4}{*}[-0.9cm]{\specialcell{Stoß-\\und\\Nahtart}}&&\specialcell{Wurzel gegen-\\geschweißte} & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\specialcell{Wurzel gegen-\\geschweißt}} & \specialcell{Wurzel\\unterlegt}&&&\specialcell{Entlastungs-\\kerbe}&\\
        &&\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{erste.png}}&\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{zweite.png}}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{dritte.png}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{vierte.png}}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{funfte.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{sechste.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{siebte.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{achte.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{neunte.png}\\
        &&&&ohne&mit&&&mit $\vert$ mit $\vert$ mit $\vert$ ohne&&mit $\vert$ ohne&\\
        &&&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Querschnittsübergang}&&&Wurzelunterlage&&\specialcell{Entlastungs-\\kerbe}&\\\hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Naht}}& bear- &\multirow{4}{*}{\textit{\bfseries A}} & \hspace{0.5cm} Durchstrahlg. & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\bfseries B} durchstrahlt}}  & \textit{\bfseries D}& \hspace*{-0.9cm} Durchstrahlung &  &\vrule\hfill & \\ \cline{4-4}\cline{9-9}
        &beitet&&\textit{\bfseries B}\hspace{0.01cm} \vrule \hfill ganz \hspace{0.5cm} & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &  stichprobenweise & \textit{\bfseries D} \vrule  \hfill ganz \vrule \hspace{0.629cm} &&\vrule\hfill&\\\cline{2-2}\cline{4-7}\cline{9-12}
        &unbear-&&\textit{\bfseries D} \vrule \hfill stichproben \hspace{0.08cm} &\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\bfseries E1}} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \textit{\bfseries D} stichprobenw. durchstr.} &  durchstrahlt & \textit{\bfseries D} \vrule \hfill stichproben \vrule \hspace{0.63cm} & & \vrule\hfill&\\\cline{9-9}\cline{4-4}\cline{6-7}
        &beitet&&\hspace{-0.109cm}\textit{\bfseries E1} \vrule \hfill ohne \hspace{0.5cm} & &&Schub \textit{\bfseries G} & \textit{\bfseries D} &\hspace{-0.109cm}\textit{\bfseries E1} \vrule \hfill ohne \hfill \vrule \hspace{0.232cm} \textit{\bfseries E1} & \textit{\bfseries E1}&\textit{\bfseries E1} \hfill\vrule\hfill \textit{\bfseries E5} \hfill& \textit{\bfseries F}\\
    \end{tabular}
```

A full document using `example-image`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength\textwidth{30cm}
\setlength\textheight{10cm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{\dimexpr1cm-1in}
\setlength\topmargin{\dimexpr1cm-1in}
\setlength\paperwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm}
\setlength\paperheight{\dimexpr\textheight+2cm}
\def\specialcell#1{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\let\zz\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\zz[height=17pt]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c@{}}
        & & \multirow{3}{*}{Grundwerkstoff}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Stumpfstoß (Gurtstoß)} & Gurtstoß & \multirow{3}{*}{\specialcell{Stegblech-\\querstoß\\(Hauptspng)}}& \multirow{3}{*}{\specialcell{Gurtstoß\\Kastenträger}} & \multirow{3}{*}{Rohrstumpfstoß} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\specialcell{Rohrverbindung\\ mit Vollrundwerkstoff}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\specialcell{Winklige \\ Rohrverbindung}}\\\cline{4-6}
        &&&gleiche&ungleiche&ungleiche&&&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&\\
        &&&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Blechdicke}&&&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&\\\hline
        &\multirow{4}{*}[-0.9cm]{\specialcell{Stoß-\\und\\Nahtart}}&&\specialcell{Wurzel gegen-\\geschweißte} & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\specialcell{Wurzel gegen-\\geschweißt}} & \specialcell{Wurzel\\unterlegt}&&&\specialcell{Entlastungs-\\kerbe}&\\
        &&\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{erste.png}}&\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{zweite.png}}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{dritte.png}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{vierte.png}}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{funfte.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{sechste.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{siebte.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{achte.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{neunte.png}\\
        &&&&ohne&mit&&&mit $\vert$ mit $\vert$ mit $\vert$ ohne&&mit $\vert$ ohne&\\
        &&&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Querschnittsübergang}&&&Wurzelunterlage&&\specialcell{Entlastungs-\\kerbe}&\\\hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Naht}}& bear- &\multirow{4}{*}{\textit{\bfseries A}} & \hspace{0.5cm} Durchstrahlg. & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\bfseries B} durchstrahlt}}  & \textit{\bfseries D}& \hspace*{-0.9cm} Durchstrahlung &  &\vrule\hfill & \\ \cline{4-4}\cline{9-9}
        &beitet&&\textit{\bfseries B}\hspace{0.01cm} \vrule \hfill ganz \hspace{0.5cm} & &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &  stichprobenweise & \textit{\bfseries D} \vrule  \hfill ganz \vrule \hspace{0.629cm} &&\vrule\hfill&\\\cline{2-2}\cline{4-7}\cline{9-12}
        &unbear-&&\textit{\bfseries D} \vrule \hfill stichproben \hspace{0.08cm} &\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\bfseries E1}} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \textit{\bfseries D} stichprobenw. durchstr.} &  durchstrahlt & \textit{\bfseries D} \vrule \hfill stichproben \vrule \hspace{0.63cm} & & \vrule\hfill&\\\cline{9-9}\cline{4-4}\cline{6-7}
        &beitet&&\hspace{-0.109cm}\textit{\bfseries E1} \vrule \hfill ohne \hspace{0.5cm} & &&Schub \textit{\bfseries G} & \textit{\bfseries D} &\hspace{-0.109cm}\textit{\bfseries E1} \vrule \hfill ohne \hfill \vrule \hspace{0.232cm} \textit{\bfseries E1} & \textit{\bfseries E1}&\textit{\bfseries E1} \hfill\vrule\hfill \textit{\bfseries E5} \hfill& \textit{\bfseries F}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: as always, your question would be clearer with an example document. If each image is in a separate cell you can just apply `\raisebox` to the image, or if you have fixed width multirow with several images just put `\vspace{-1in}` at the top or the fixup optional argument  or ...

Comment: There's a `CTRL-K` way to format code as such ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for taking the time to fix this mess, not even I was sure what belongs to what anymore.

Comment: do you need multirow at all? from your image I'd put all the images in a single normal row.  The vertical/horizontal gaps  in the lines around `Querschnittsübergang` look very confusing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle They indeed are confusing, but this is a table from a textbook that I need to recreate 1:1 unfortunately.

Comment: scan the thing and include it as an image:-) (well actually not a smiley, I'd consider doing that)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is a reason I wrote "recreate".. Anyways, I just aligned everything manually  now. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @Skydiver I'm out of time on this but I added a MWE in case it is of use to anyone who wants to attempt an answer. Feel free to delete it if you feel it's misleading. (notably  perhaps because all the images are same size)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much! It actually shouldn't be a problem that the example images are all the same size, they only thing that needs to be figured out is how to automatically center the images after all.

Comment: well as I said I'd put all the images in a single non multi-row row so then they will align with each other naturally and if they are same height even baseline will do. You can put the caption things on the rows above or below.